# Gradle: 'compile' cannot be applied

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

Today I started a new JDK 11 project with Gradle 5.0 (using the Gradle Wrapper) and created a basic build script:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gradle:osdetector-gradle-plugin:1.6.0'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.osdetector'

ext.platform = osdetector.os == 'osx' ? 'mac' : osdetector.os == 'windows' ? 'win' : osdetector.os

version = '0.1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:11:$platform"
}
```

This - rather basic - build script results in the error

> 'compile' in 'org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler' cannot
>   be applied to '(groovy.lang.GString)'

[image]

Is that a JDK 11, a Gradle 5.0 or a user error? I've never seen that before.

Comment: Have you tried using single quote?

Comment: @yahavi With single quotes, I believe one cannot use string substitution like `$foo`.

Comment: Your build script looks fine. Just to give it a try: can you use ${platform} to declare the compile dependency?

Comment: @Frito Just tried it: Same issue, tho.

Comment: Yet another try: compile "org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:11:${platform}".toString()

Comment: Using IntelliJ? I can see several messages like yours in IntelliJ after upgrading to Gradle 5. But the build works on command line.

Comment: @Frito Since I have the Ultimate edition I will contact support.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in IntelliJ, you should open an issue in the jetbrains issue tracker. Having the same issue, my build script works fine, it's just IntelliJ.

Comment: @kevcodez Thanks for the clarification; just did so!

Answer (score 7):

According to JetBrains support this is a known bug and will be fixed in `2018.3.1`.

See: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-203393

Comment: happen to me on version 2018.3.3. Something i touch made change the definition and suddenly all file was filled with errors.

Comment: This bug remains present in version 2019.1

Comment: 2019.1.3 still remains wtf

Answer (score 0):

The messages only appear within IntelliJ using Gradle 5.0 (e.g. 2018.3).
The build works fine, started from console or from IntelliJ.